# in-app purchase help

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Hi all 
I want to use in app purchase in my app ,please help from where I should start .

Comment: Dude...I can definitely help you with this one...as i have successfully implemented it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all **GO THOROUGHLY THROUGH** [THIS](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) link.When i started out developing for an In App purchase,i took help from this Blog and it helped me a LOT...

Secondly read the  [Apple documentation on In App purchase](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW12)  too..It is also a good source of information.

I can tell you from my experience is that,in implementing In App purchase 85% of your time would be consumed in R&D.Once you understand it,then its like a child's play...

So ALL THE BEST....

Cheers

Comment: @Ali..I saw your previous question and they were on APNS which im yet to implement...SO couldn't answer those..anyways ALL THE BEST for In App..

Comment: I implemented the APNS using urbanAirShip

Comment: Oh Cool..So how was the experience implementing it?

Comment: Using urbanAirShip its very easy but when I wanted to implement using direct APNS server but it became impossible due to dedicated server and low level socket issues ,so I decided to implement using urbanAir